# query string http%3A%2F%2F turns into http%253A%252F%252

Tags: php, url, uri, encode

I have a problem with query string symbols.

I'm redirecting user to this link

```
payment.php?pg_amount=294.91&pg_check_url=http%3A%2F%2Fofficecorp.ru%2Fplatron%2Fcheck.php&pg_description=order+number+%2339&pg_failure_url=http%3A%2F%2Fofficecorp.ru%2Fplatron%2Ffailure.php&pg_failure_url_method=POST&pg_lifetime=86400&pg_merchant_id=4726&pg_order_id=39&pg_refund_url=http%3A%2F%2Fofficecorp.ru%2Fplatron%2Frefund.php&pg_request_method=POST&pg_result_url=http%3A%2F%2Fofficecorp.ru%2Fplatron%2Fresult.php&pg_salt=52ed1c15ce83b&pg_site_url=http%3A%2F%2Fofficecorp.ru&pg_success_url=http%3A%2F%2Fofficecorp.ru%2Fplatron%2Fsuccess.php&pg_success_url_method=AUTOPOST&pg_testing_mode=1&pg_user_contact_email=t.muradyan%40platron.ru&pg_user_mail=t.muradyan%40platron.ru&pg_user_phone=79163763072&status_failed=R&status_ok=D&status_revoked=V&pg_sig=134921022b548f00daed122f8249b003
```

But it turns into

```
https://www.platron.ru/payment.php?pg_amount=294.91&pg_check_url=http%253A%252F%252Fofficecorp.ru%252Fplatron%252Fcheck.php&pg_description=order+number+%252339&pg_failure_url=http%253A%252F%252Fofficecorp.ru%252Fplatron%252Ffailure.php&pg_failure_url_method=POST&pg_lifetime=86400&pg_merchant_id=4726&pg_order_id=39&pg_refund_url=http%253A%252F%252Fofficecorp.ru%252Fplatron%252Frefund.php&pg_request_method=POST&pg_result_url=http%253A%252F%252Fofficecorp.ru%252Fplatron%252Fresult.php&pg_salt=52ed1c15ce83b&pg_site_url=http%253A%252F%252Fofficecorp.ru&pg_success_url=http%253A%252F%252Fofficecorp.ru%252Fplatron%252Fsuccess.php&pg_success_url_method=AUTOPOST&pg_testing_mode=1&pg_user_contact_email=t.muradyan%2540platron.ru&pg_user_mail=t.muradyan%2540platron.ru&pg_user_phone=79163763072&status_failed=R&status_ok=D&status_revoked=V&pg_sig=134921022b548f00daed122f8249b003
```

The letters  http%3A%2F%2F turns into http%253A%252F%252.

```
$strQuery = http_build_query($arrRequest);

$strQuery 

pg_amount=294.91&pg_check_url=http%3A%2F%2Fofficecorp.ru%2Fplatron%2Fcheck.php&pg_description=order+number+%2339&pg_failure_url=http%3A%2F%2Fofficecorp.ru%2Fplatron%2Ffailure.php&pg_failure_url_method=POST&pg_lifetime=86400&pg_merchant_id=4726&pg_order_id=39&pg_refund_url=http%3A%2F%2Fofficecorp.ru%2Fplatron%2Frefund.php&pg_request_method=POST&pg_result_url=http%3A%2F%2Fofficecorp.ru%2Fplatron%2Fresult.php&pg_salt=52ed1c15ce83b&pg_site_url=http%3A%2F%2Fofficecorp.ru&pg_success_url=http%3A%2F%2Fofficecorp.ru%2Fplatron%2Fsuccess.php&pg_success_url_method=AUTOPOST&pg_testing_mode=1&pg_user_contact_email=t.muradyan%40platron.ru&pg_user_mail=t.muradyan%40platron.ru&pg_user_phone=79163763072&status_failed=R&status_ok=D&status_revoked=V&pg_sig=134921022b548f00daed122f8249b003
```

There is a problem with encoding. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, that the `%`-symbol gets encoded (The hex-value of % is 0x25).

You don't have to manually encode the url, just put your url (with all your special symbols) in the link, and encoding will be done automatically.

**The code should look like this afterwards:**

```
$strQuery = http_build_query($arrRequest);

$strQuery 

pg_amount=294.91&pg_check_url=http://officecorp.ru/platron/check.php&pg_description=order number #39&pg_failure_url=http://officecorp.ru/platron/failure.php&pg_failure_url_method=POST&pg_lifetime=86400&pg_merchant_id=4726&pg_order_id=39&pg_refund_url=http://officecorp.ru/platron/refund.php&pg_request_method=POST&pg_result_url=http://officecorp.ru/platron/result.php&pg_salt=52ed1c15ce83b&pg_site_url=http://officecorp.ru&pg_success_url=http://officecorp.ru/platron/success.php&pg_success_url_method=AUTOPOST&pg_testing_mode=1&pg_user_contact_email=t.muradyan@platron.ru&pg_user_mail=t.muradyan@platron.ru&pg_user_phone=79163763072&status_failed=R&status_ok=D&status_revoked=V&pg_sig=134921022b548f00daed122f8249b003
```